# Current limit in boost converter

Tags: boost

The schematic is made by Great scott (a YouTuber).I need to know can we add a current limit to it by using a sense resistor and feeding the sensed voltage proportional to the current in the feedback controller opamp?[image]My question is can I add the output of this current limit part  to the voltage feedback controller opamp?(in the inverting input)?[image][image]

Comment: You've summed up what you need to do; put a shunt resistor in line on of the power rail, use an op-amp to amplify the voltage across said resistor. The question is what you do with this current limit, do you want a micro controller to read it? Do you want the signal to trigger a transistor to turn something off/on?

Comment: Yeah my bad ..I forgot to mention that .I was going for adjustable current limiting.

Comment: And what happens when there is an over current event?

Comment: Well that is why i wanna add a current limit function to it @Puffafish

Answer (score 1):

With this topology, it's not possible to implement a current limit. See the current path? It's from the Vcc power source through L1 and D1 into the load.

*There is no switched element in that path.*

To add a current limit, you'd had to add a switch in the current path. Because a conducting MOSFET has lower losses than a diode, it is adviseable to put another MOSFET in **instead** of the diode D1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBXf6Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The path over R_limit and the diode is for preventing T1 and/or T2 to be shot by overvoltage if T1 is opened while current is flowing through L1 and T2 is not opened because of the current limiting function.